# Statistics on Hazelcast DurableExecutorService?

Tags: hazelcast

How can I get statistics on Hazelcast DurableExecutorService?
It looks like there is no MBean for that executorService so JMX cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast does not collect statistics for DurableExecutorService as of yet.